# How to calculate Metabolic Age statistically by using formula(without using weighing machine or any online calculators)?

Tags: metabolism, reference-request

How are we supposed to calculate our metabolic age if we have results of a person that includes: `age` `gender` `weight` `height` `BMI` and `BMR`?

I have researched a lot but I am not able to find the formula for calculating metabolic age according to the variables I gave above. Can someone provide me with a source for the formula?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using machine"? The formula is well known, published in many hundreds of places, and there are quite a few calculators available on the web.

Comment: @JohnP I meant without using any other weighing machine or without using online calculators. I need to know the formula and the chart by which we compare the BMR to the average BMR of your chronological age group. I have searched alot of sites but none provided me the formula and even if they did I am unable to find the BMr standard chart for age group of 5 to 60+

Comment: @HardikSisodia I edited your question to reflect what you explained in your answer to John. If you dislike my edits you can roll them back by clicking the 'edit' link.